# How do I move my hamburger in css and still have it functional?

Tags: html, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

So i have made a website with HTML and CSS. It has different effects like the parallax effect(a very simple version of it), transparent navbar, and now I am trying to make my Navbar responsive. Everything works, but my hamburger menu is very far to the left and when I find a way to move it, it doesnt work after i moved it.

[image]

As you can see it is very close to the top of the screne and so far to the left that it is past the logo. I want it to stay to the right even if i made the screen smaller ofr bigger, like it moves with the screen when i move it.

This is my css code:

```css
  @font-face {
        font-family: 'Poppins';
        src: url(Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
    }
    
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Comfortaa';
        src: url(Fonts/Comfortaa-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
    }
    
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'DancingScript';
        src: url(Fonts/DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
    }
    
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: #A6808C;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #565264;
        font-family: Poppins;
    }
    
    html {
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    } 
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0%;
    } 
    
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 10px 90px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
        z-index: 9999
    }
    
    
    nav .logo {
        padding: -22px 20px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
        line-height: 60px;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 12px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    nav ul li a:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .text {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: #565264;
        color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .title {
        font-size: 7rem;
        color: whitesmoke;
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    }
    
    
    .background {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(3);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    header {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    
    .wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        perspective: 10px;
    }
    
    .hamburger {
        position: relative;
        width: 30px;
        height: 4px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .hamburger:before, .hamburger:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 4px;
        right: 0;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    
    }
    
    .hamburger:before {
        top: -10px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    .hamburger:after {
        top: 10px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    .toggle-menu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 3;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .hamburger, .toggle-menu {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger {
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    .navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger::before {
       top: 0;
       transform: rotate(-45deg);
       width: 30px;
    }
    
    .navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger::after {
        top: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        width: 30px;
     }
    
     .navigation input:checked ~ .menu {
        right: 0;
        box-shadow: -20px 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     }
    
     @media screen and (max-width: 1062px) {
        .hamburger, .toggle-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    
        .header {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
    
        nav ul {
            justify-content: start;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: -300px;
            background-color: #565264;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 65px;
        }
    
        .menu li {
            width: 100%;
        }
    
        .menu li a, .menu li a:hover {
           padding: 30px; 
           font-size: 24px;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(112,102,119,0.5) inset;
        }
     }
```

```html
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initalscale=1.0">
        <Title>Test</Title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="Pictures\Logo DesignK whitegreen.png" alt="DesignK" height="50px" width="200px">
                </a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="navigation">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-menu">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
    
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
        </nav>
    
    
    
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img src="Pictures/LakeandMoutains.jpg" class="background">
                <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
            </header>
    
        
    
        <section class="text">
            <h3>Essay on Mountains</h3>
    
    </section>
    
            </div>
    </body>
```

Does anyone know how to make the hamburger menu move to the right side of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `.hamburger, .toggle-menu` styles like this

```
.hamburger, .toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
}
```

Update the value of `right` according to your need.

Comment: I tried this, but once I started I move it, I could no longer open the hamburgera menu. Do you know why?

Comment: @Atrageous probably because it gets overlapped by something else now. Use the "inspect element" function of your browser dev tools, in the position where that click doesn't do what it should - and then see what element you actually land on with that, in the elements panel.

Comment: @Atrageous
it works fine for me. Please try updating the code inside the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 1062px)`

Answer (score 0):

You could always use flexbox. The following lines of code will display this on the right hand side:-

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: So now the hamburger is right beside the logo. Is there a way to change that code so it wont be that close all the time? like more to the right end of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the importance of HTML structure and positioning because this is the problem in your HTML.

To fix your problem, you need to put the burger menu and the check box in one container and then position the container.

The problem now is that you are positioning every part individually and their width and height are not properly set.

try to follow the steps I mentioned then let us know if you can do it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your navigation class:

```
.navigation{
position:relative;
}
```

and then this to your hamburger menu to make it stick to the right.

```
.hamburger{
  position:relative;
  right:8%;
}
```

The position absolute will make the hamburger-menu stick relative to the navigation bar and right 8% will stick it to the right.